# R language multiple values for adj parameter in text() call

Tags: r, text, offset

A question and a meta-question:

In the R statistics language, I would like to give an independent offset when printing a bunch of values to a plot.

Specifying offset for a SINGLE string is easy:

```
text(0,0, "offset this", adj=0)
```

I am printing multiple values from a matrix; call it `database`, with columns `x`, `y`, `label`, and `offset`:

```
attach(database)
text(x,y, label, adj=offset)
```

This does not work.  Apparently adj only accepts the first two values, interpreting them as horizontal and vertical offsets.  I tried giving it a 2Xn or nx2 matrix, but it still only uses the first two values.

Of course, I could just do this:

```
   text(x+offset*strwidth(label), y, label)
```

but I'm wondering if there is a way I can use adj instead.

Meta-question:
   Is there any way to look at the code for a function that does not show up when you type the name of the function?

R version linux-gnu 3.2.1  2015-06-18

Comment: For the "meta" question; do google search on "accessing the sources ligges".

Comment: **NEVER** use `attach()`. It causes far more problems than it's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, don't use `attach`. If you have multiple values to pass to a function that is not prepared for them you might try `mapply`>

```
> plot(NA, xlim=c(0,10), ylim=c(0,10))
> invisible( mapply(text, y=1:10, x=1, labels="ttttttt" , adj=runif(10) ) )
```

You do understand that 'adj' is relative the size of the label argument, right?

Comment: Thanks, especially for the answer to the 'meta' question!